# What is the name of a guy who comment highlights in NBA

Tags: basketball, trivia, nba, media

Does anyone know the name of the guy who does most of the postgame highlights on NBA.

- http://www.nba.com/video/games/heat/2013/11/09/0021300089-bos-mia-recap.nba
- http://www.nba.com/video/games/bulls/2013/11/16/0021300140-ind-chi-recap.nba
- http://www.nba.com/video/games/rockets/2013/11/16/0021300141-den-hou-recap.nba

Comment: Scanned through the source of the pages, but it doesn't look like they supply anything about him. His voice is unfamiliar to me.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't find anything on nba.com page. But he has cool voice. I know last season someone substituted him for a week or so, and those highlights were unwatchable. (:

Comment: if you're really interested, i'm sure you could contact nba.com's support email and they'd give you his Twitter handle or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

His name is Beau Estes, here is another video of him introducing himself:

http://www.nba.com/video/channels/nba_tv/2014/07/10/20140710-free-agency-update.nba/