# Who is this particular English Premiership (Rugby Union) lead announcer?

Tags: trivia, media, rugby-union

http://youtu.be/tcoNn0lskgw?t=2m40s

He should be listed somewhere in here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_British_football_commentators

> A Meta entry said this question would be better received if given the reason for the question.
>
> ...So I can have a means to avoid watching anything he ever anouces (pretty much anything Aviva Premiership) because of that tedious gritted-teeth affectation thing he does - fabricating drama.  (It sounds like he's announcing from a toilet seat, and occasionally trying to squeeze one out while speaking.)
>
> And just the whole English boarding-school thing in general, when they are forcing it with stilted pronunciations.  David Croft (Sky Formula 1) Ted Kravitz and Simone Lazenby – are the worst.  Ponce hipster central.  Crofty has this nervous tick.  He says “nOWW” too often for no good reason; other than to make himself sound posh. (http://youtu.be/OS7WoUzcWT4?t=4s)
>
> That said: **Jack Burnicle** and **James Whitham** are great – and happen to be English and have their own more natural affectations.  Right and proper Yorkshire, I believe.  Or maybe theirs is just called a "Northern" accent - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b5Mbh8_FAhc)
>
> /Rant over.

Comment: Yet, we have this question: https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3526/what-is-the-name-of-a-guy-who-comment-highlights-in-nba?rq=1 I see no difference between the two in terms of what's being asked. **Case in point: let's be consistent in how we evaluate questions. [(meta discussion)](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/520/media-are-announcer-commentator-identification-questions-on-topic)**

Comment: I am on your side here. I could either close this question as requested by the community, as a source/research request, or you can remove the trivia tag and leave it be.

Comment: Oh.  Sorry Ed.  To the others then: announcers are part and parcel to professional sport; particularly when they are themselves significant capped rugby players.  (Albeit, not in this particular case – surely.)  Hence the valid _“media”_ tag.

Comment: Viewing the given video, I guess you can focus your research on commentators from sportsnet. Unfortunately I was not able to find more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe **Miles Harrison** is the man.

After watching quite a few matches on YouTube to see if they would list or call each other out by name (never happened once) I found this by cross referencing a long list of announcer names - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FWRYM0ZJZRw